# Flatpak - packaging a binary

Tags: build, binary, packaging, builder, flatpak

I am starting with FlatPak. I'm trying to package a binary application (I don't have to build it -is already compiled-). How should I proceed?

I manage to download it and check the sha256. I don't know how to tell under *sources* not to build this .tgz just to uncompress it.

Regards,
José M.